# Why can't I kill my contract on my private blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-invocation, private-blockchain, greeter

Deployed to my private net, can call the contract, but can't kill:

```
> greeter.greet()
"Hello World again."
> greeterSource
"contract mortal { address owner; function mortal() { owner = msg.sender; } function kill() { if (msg.sender == owner) suicide(owner); } } contract greeter is mortal { string greeting; function greeter(string _greeting) public { greeting = _greeting; } function greet() constant returns (string) { return greeting; } }"
> greeter.kill()
invalid address
    at web3.js:3887:15
    at web3.js:3713:20
    at web3.js:4939:28
    at web3.js:4938:12
    at web3.js:4964:18
    at web3.js:4989:23
    at web3.js:4055:16
    at web3.js:4141:16
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Don't think `kill` needs an address, does it?

Answer (score 4):

The [Greeter tutorial page](https://www.ethereum.org/greeter) on the official site clearly states how to run the `kill` method under the "Cleaning up after yourself" section.

```
greeter.kill.sendTransaction({from:eth.accounts[0]})
```